# Select tag is not rendering inside table but can see in the view source

Tags: jquery, html

I am having a strange problem where I put a HTML select tag in a table inside div. In view source I can see the tag is showing view source but not rendered as HTML .Attached is the fig
Where could be I went wrong

[image]

Actually I am adding the table dynamically.
JSP:`

```
<tbody id="t_columns_list" class="ul-body-b aa content ul-body-b-big ul-dd">

                    </tbody>
```

`

JQUERY:

```
gridTemplate:'<tr class="ul-list-b"><td class="lic-3-4"><%=columnName%></td><td class="lic-3-4"><%=dataType%></td><td class="lic-3-4 "><div ><select name="action_col"><option value="">None</option>'+
         '</select></div></td><td class="lic-4-4" style="text-align:center"><button class="btn-b">Edit</button></td><td class="lic-4-4" style="text-align:center"></td><td class= "lic-4-4" style="text-align:center"><input type="text" style="width:150px;"></td><td class="lic-4-4" style="text-align:center"><input type="checkbox" id="invalid"></td><td class="lic-4-4" style="text-align:center"><input type="text" style="width:150px;"></td></tr>',


         render:function(eventName){
            var self=this;

             // var grid = $("#t_columns_list");
              var grid = $(this.el).find('#t_columns_list');
              grid.show();
              var listHtml = "";
            if(this.model.models.length > 0){
                this.tableCount = this.model.models.length;

                   _.each(this.model.models, function (table,i) {
                       var table_item = table.toJSON();
                       table_item.ownerName = table_item.ownerName || "";

                       _.each(table_item.columns,function(column,i){
                           this.columnCount++;
                           listHtml += _.template(this.gridTemplate,column);
                       },this);
                    }, this);
                   grid.html(listHtml);

                   $(this.el).find('table').colResizable();
            }

            //call ajax
            var navigation_tabs = $("#nav_simulate");
            _.each(this.model.models, function (table,i) {
                   var table_item = table.toJSON();
                   table_item.ownerName = table_item.ownerName || "";
                navigation_tabs.append('<li>'+table_item.tableName+'</li>');
            });



    }
```

Comment: Paste Some Code of your html

Comment: Sometimes an image can't replace a thousand words. Show us some code.

Comment: Could be due to some styling rules

Comment: Why that class has a space? `<td class="lic-3-4 ">`

Comment: what is the css code for the class "lic-3-4" ?

Comment: @MelanciaUK It's probably been added dynamically, but either way it makes 0 difference.

Comment: Have you tried with 'value="something"' inside option tag?

Comment: @MelanciaUK style for .lic-3-4{width:100px;}

Comment: It's totally related to css positioning, try searching for the styles of the td as well as your select with some tool like firbug or web developer toolbar plugin.

Comment: this is alredy working in another page.The same copied here is not working here

Comment: You may not have copied enough CSS.